# TableView reloadData() not works on Closure Block in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I've a function to get data from web service, my func download data and put on database, when I call `self.tableView.reloadData()` I take the objects from database and refresh list, but the method `reloadData()` is not calling.

I Also tried call: `self.tableViewItens.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(UICollectionView.reloadData), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)`
Also, I tried put `self.tableViewItens.reloadData()` outside of completion closure, not works too.

action of UITabBarButton:

```
@objc func refreshButton() {

    Sync.syncData(tabela: "my_table", successBlock: { (n) in
        print("Refreshed: \(n)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.tableViewItens.reloadData()                
        }
    }) { (err) in
        print(err)                
    }   
}
```

Method not called:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 print("cellForRowAt")
 return UITableViewCell()

}

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listaDados.count
    }
```

viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.alerta = Alerta()

    self.rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(refreshButton))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.rightButton
    self.title = titlePage!
    self.tableViewItens.delegate = self
    self.tableViewItens.dataSource = self

}
```

I don't put the code of `Sync.syncData()` because this works, only thing that not works is the `reloadData()` of table view.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show your table view implementation. Make sure you are setting the view controller as the table view delegate

Comment: Oh man, of course I do this. Without closure block the code works

Comment: Have you implemented numberofrowsinsection delegate method? Even if you have implemented it make sure there are items in your datasource array or else cellforrowatindexpath will not get called.

Comment: Does it work if you call it under `showWait`?

Comment: do you have `numberOfRowsInSection` method implemented ?

Comment: Yes, I have. The list view works. Only in this case at question not works

Comment: Is the completion block getting called?

Comment: Yes, this works too

Comment: I meant is your dismissWait completion block being called?

Comment: I think I have found out the problem. The thing is you are trying to reload after dismissing your controller. How do you expect your tableview to be present after dismissing the controller itself? So basically it won't work if you put it inside the dismissWait completion block. Put it outside and it will work.

Comment: I was forgetting of load data on the list :)